# How do I dynamically set a variable in Artillery to use in my Playwright function

Tags: load-testing, playwright, artillery

I create a variable in my yml artillery file which I can then access from my Playwright function.

```
variables:
    redirectUrl: "foo"
```

I then dynamically assign a url I get from an api call to this variable.

```
- post:
          url: "/ipgw/wrapper/v1/customer-token/{{guid}}/pay"
          form:
            amount: 10
            reference:  "{{uuid}}"
            return_url: "https://www.google.com/"
          capture:
            - json: "$.url"
              as: "redirectUrl"
```

However I cannot figure out how to dynamically set that redirectUrl variable by using the response from an api call I make just before I call that function.

The below function picks up on the placeholder value of 'foo' and not the value I dynamically assign that I get from the api response.

```
async function ipgHostedPages(page, context) {
    await page.goto(context.vars['redirectUrl']);

    await page.getByPlaceholder('CVV').fill('***');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Pay' }).click();

    await page.getByLabel('Password:').fill('***');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Submit' }).click();
    await page.getByText('Redirect Now').click();
}
```